# Positioning a button within an image in CSS

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I would want to insert a button within an image using CSS; the image has a fixed width and height, centered in the page.
The button must remain stationary within the image at different resolution.

Comment: Can you post the code for the image?

Comment: Can you put some code in a jsFiddle so we can work on it?

Comment: This is the link https://jsfiddle.net/4sk9rvng/
The link of the image is in the src attribute of the tag img
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS doesn't allow other elements inside an `<img>` tag. My common go-to in this situation is put both your image and button inside two wrapper `<div>` elements that act like a table (vertically and horizontally centered). *Like so;*

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="[your image src]">
    <a class="button" href="[go to page]">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  display: table;
  width: 100%; /* Add or remove this depending on your layout */
}
.wrapper > div{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

As long as the image has no size constraints this should sit flush in the center of the image :). Enjoy!

***EDIT*** ---

Alternatively, remove the `<img>` tag and put it as a background-image of `.wrapper` and use background-size: cover; to center it :). Then you can control the height and width of the image really easily.

*Remember to use vendor prefixes too. I have a handy list of them [here](https://andycrone.com/current-list-sass-mixins-vendor-prefixes/) although they are in Sass.*

Comment: No, i'm not sure that i understood.
This is my code...first problem is that the image is not centered.

https://jsfiddle.net/4sk9rvng/7/

notes: button test should be where indicated by the arrow;
image should be centered;

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS:

```
myImage {
background-image:url('image.jpg');
background-size:cover;
}
```

be sure to give your button an ID

in your HTML

```
<button id='myImage' type='submit'>&nbsp;</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To put the button in the position where you want it, simply give it some margins:

```css
.wrapper button {
    margin-left:81%; margin-top:3%;
}
```

But I believe you want the div with the background image to never be larger than the window, right? In that case, you will need some more CSS: set a max-width and a max-height on the div, and then you will also need to set both html and body to a fixed width and height, otherwise max-width and max-height won't know what they ought to be relative to.
So, that's

```css
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}

.wrapper {
    (..)
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:100%; max-height:100%;
}
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/4sk9rvng/8/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but I don't want the form in the middle..I would like the form where indicated by the arrow of the image..

Comment: I think that it doesn't work, when i resize the window (or change resolution)...this is the right fiddle, if you want to help me https://jsfiddle.net/4sk9rvng/7/

Comment: Thanks, you are quite close to the solution.
But there is a problem...try to resize the window of the browser (make it smaller)...

Comment: You mean you want to make the button smaller in that case?

Comment: no, but this is the effect
http://s13.postimg.org/z1i7qlffr/Schermata_del_2015_06_01_22_05_26.png

Comment: I've been thinking, and I don't believe there is a way to do this in CSS only. You'll have to create some JavaScript, triggered by a resize, that repositions the button if necessary. Also, `background-size:contain` for the image is probably better, because `cover` will not have the entire image in view when the window is too narrow.

Comment: ok, thanks.
I 'solved' using a css query....it's not a good implementation, but that's all.
https://jsfiddle.net/4sk9rvng/9/